# Map like google maps, but over a facility, hospital, commercial center...

Tags: jquery, html, web, maps

How to create a interactive map like google maps, over facilites, builds, parks, anything. In this case is Airport: http://www.gru.com.br/pt-br/Guia-do-Aeroporto/Cias-Aereas (Bottom)
What is the technology to use?

Comment: It seems like they developed own jquery plugin for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [leafletjs](http://leafletjs.com/) before and it's very nice and easy.